# Making a plot label containing dynamically subscripted symbols

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting

```
Manipulate[
  Plot....
    Epilog -> 
     {Text["Al" <> ToString[x]<>"Ga" <> ToString[1 - x] <> "As", {0.5, 2}]}],
  {x, 0, 1}]
```

But I want the values of `x` and `1 - x` to appear as subscripts in the text string. How cam I do this?

Comment: Why does it have to be a string? I would do `Row[{Subscript["Al", x], Subscript["Ga", 1 - x], "As"}]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Carl Woll say in his comment, this better done with `Row`.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[{}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{Subscript["Al", u], Subscript["Ga", 1 - u], "As"}]],
  {{u, 0, "Al"}, {0, 1}, SetterBar}]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to get this to work using Row.
Although the Epilog with Text gave me more flexibility to locate the label.

Comment: @Brian. This was only meant to illustrate the use of `Row` and `SetterBar`, so I didn't worry about placement, which wasn't relevant to you problem. I'm glad you found the answer helpful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.